# Retrofit slash as Query

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to download data from this api:

https://chicken-coop.fr/rest/games/fifa%2019?platform=switch

This is my **Interface class**:

```
public interface GamesInterface {
    @GET("/rest/games")
    Call<Example> getGamesbyName(@Query("/") String gameName, @Query("platform") String gamePlatform);
}
```

Currently I can change platform name in my layout using a spinner,  but I don't know how I can change the game name. How can I use slash as `@Query("platform")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
public interface GamesInterface {
    @GET("/rest/games/{gameName}")
    Call<Example> getGamesbyName(@Path("gameName") String gameName, @Query("platform") String gamePlatform);
}
```

Note the `@Path` annotation, which maps a `String` into the url. You can read more about Retrofit, with examples, at this url: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Thank you @Giovanni Terlingen